# OPTIMIZE QUERY ON RAILS - POSTGRESQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 scopes:
1 - lists the promotions in progress.
2 - sort out of stock last
3 - list the promotions that are not in progress.

Is it possible to combine everything in a single scope? It would be: List the promotions in progress, in order of stock from highest to lowest, and then the promotions that are not in progress.

I tried, but I couldn't.

```
scope :in_progress, -> { start_and_end_dates.in_weeks.between_hours }
    
scope :without_stock_last, lambda {
  select('promotions.*, (CASE WHEN offers.current_inventory > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "is_available"')
   .order('is_available DESC')
   .group('promotions.id, offers.current_inventory, offers.created_at')
}
    
scope :not_progress, lambda {
  promotions_in_progress = Promotion.in_progress.pluck(:id).join(",")
  Promotion.with_estabilishment.select("promotions.*, (CASE WHEN promotions.id NOT IN (#{promotions_in_progress}) THEN 0 END) AS is_unavailable")
  .order('is_unavailable DESC')
}
```

Comment: The first scope doesn't even work?  There is no join so it can't possibly select columns from both the `promotions` and `offers` tables. Its impossible to optimize code without a good description of what the code is supposed to do, an example of the data and the expected output. Hell you havent even shown us what model this code belongs in.

Comment: "I tried, but I couldn't." is something toddlers say - not programmers. Tell us what you actually tried and what didn't work so that we at least have a starting point and know what you struggled with. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand what you're trying to do is to get in_progress showing first in the result and then you have the not in progress coming next. You can just as the scope `:find_all` concat the result of the results of the other two.

I supposed that (correct me if I'm wrong) that you have One to Many relationship between Promotion and Offer. So what I do in the `without_stock_last` scope is to join the offers and set a condition where current_inventory greater than 2.

For the `not_in_progress` you can just do a where.not to do an exclusion of result from the `in_progress scope`

```rb
scope :in_progress, -> { start_and_end_dates.in_weeks.between_hours }
scope :without_stock_last, -> { joins(:offfers).where(offers: {current_inventory: 2..})  }
scope :not_in_progress, -> { where.not(id: in_progress) }
scope :find_all, -> { without_stock_last + not_in_progress }
```

Please provide a more clear description of the model you have and what optimization you want to make.

thank